# Using a control sequence in multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn

I have this code giving me an error:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|ccccccccc|}
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\textbf{Table Heading}} &  
\makecell{8-16-bit\\fixed-point} & 230 & \makecell{HLS} & 
\makecell{1682\\1644} & \makecell{5120\\4480} & 
\makecell{39\%\\38\%} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{46\%\\42\%} & \makecell{75\%\\65\%} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Line `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{46\%\\42\%}` is giving me an error something about \cr. I am sure the error is about using an escape sequence in `multicolumn{}{}{\escapesequences}`, looking for a way to use them in multicolumn.

Comment: I'm quite sure this is caused by the use of `\\ ` in a `c` type column.

Comment: a `c` column is for single line, centred cells, you don't say what you want `\\ ` to do in that context. Also please always post complete small documents that generate the error so people can see the problem. Your fragment uses several non standard commands that you leave people to guess which packages are needed to define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ *{10}{c} }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Table Heading}} \\ 
    \midrule
\makecell[b]{8-16-bit\\fixed-point} 
    &   \makecell[b]{230}
    &   \makecell[b]{HLS}
    &   \makecell[b]{1682\\1644}
    &   \makecell[b]{5120\\4480}   
    &   \makecell[b]{\SI{39}{\%}\\ \SI{38}{\%}}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell[b]{\SI{46}{\%}\\ \SI{42}{\%}}} % <---
    &   \makecell[b]{\SI{75}{\%}\\ \SI{65}{\%}} \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

is this what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks @zarko , quick question - what is \SI{}{}

Comment: @DeathstrokeTwelved, it is macro for writing values with units: `\SI{<number>}{<unit>}`. For details see the  `siunitx` package documentation. It is part of your LaTeX installation and also available in https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx